# How to have a "quick launch" like icons in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

In windows XP, there was the quick launch icons.  If I where to turn a program on, I would still be able to start another instance of it through the quick launch bar.

In windows 7 I can't do that since when I start the program, the icon expends and then I can't start a new instance of the program.

Any ideas for solutions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Middle-clicking (mouse wheel) on the icon also opens a new instance. Otherwise stijn's answer will give you back the quicklaunch bar.

Comment: cool, didn't know that

Comment: Got my vote - great tip!

Comment: didnt know about middle click..ive been right clicking it.

Answer (score 5):

right-click icon, select name of program or recent document and another instance opens. Or, if you want the actual QuickLaunch toolbar, right-click taskbar, select 'New toolbar' and enter this address:

```
C:\Users\(user-name)\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch
```

Comment: You answered my question - but Jaips gave me what I needed :)  You get +1

Answer (score 1):

You can use the shortcut key

> <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>[number]</kbd>

where [number] is the position of the item you want to launch a new instance of. For example, if Notepad was the first program in your toolbar, you could use <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd>.

If you don't use the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, you can launch a new instance of the program if one does not exist, or minimize/maximize one that does.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + Click in the icon will also create a new instance of the application in Windows 7